# How to draw a balloon shape in Android which expands and contracts when user click buttons

Tags: android, image, canvas, draw

I want to draw a ballon shape object in any color, when user clicks on (+) button the ballon expands and when user clicks (-) ballon contracts.

I have drawn a circle in canvas but its not in ballon shape. I used following code

```
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(4.5f);
canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```

and even I have drawn the circle how to expand or contract it when user click buttons.

Thanks

Comment: Try drawOval.  A baloon is an oval-ish shape.  If that isn't balloony enough (if you want it to be more top heavy), you'll have to use a path and bezier splines, which gets into complicated math.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier, if you used a 9 patch? You would only have to change the ImageView's width...